# how to debug python core dump file

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, ctypes, coredump

My program is python, and call .so(which is c++ code) by ctypes lib. Then in a specific PC this program will be core dumped but has not issue in other PC. PC's os is ubuntu.

I use gdb to debug the generated core dump file core.python_2290670_11_1659426925_lp-r03-n15, get following info. It shows python dealloc a dict, but which dict it is? Do you know how to get more debug info?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  dict_dealloc (mp=0x7fd574b73830) at ../Objects/dictobject.c:1085
#1  subtype_dealloc (self=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/typeobject.c:1035
#2  0x000055bf717ad302 in dict_dealloc (mp=0x7fd574b73b90) at ../Objects/dictobject.c:1086
#3  subtype_dealloc (self=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/typeobject.c:1035
#4  0x000055bf717442b5 in list_dealloc (op=0x7fd585eca3c0) at ../Objects/listobject.c:309
#5  0x000055bf7177682f in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:1258
#6  0x000055bf7176d84c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7fd59c256630, globals=<optimized out>, 
    locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, 
    kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=<optimized out>, defs=<optimized out>, 
    defcount=<optimized out>, closure=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3608
#7  0x000055bf71775833 in fast_function (nk=8, na=1, n=<optimized out>, 
    pp_stack=0x7fff484ab218, func=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4471
#8  call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fff484ab218) at ../Python/ceval.c:4396
#9  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3013
#10 0x000055bf7177559d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=1, 
    pp_stack=0x7fff484ab328, func=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4461
#11 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fff484ab328) at ../Python/ceval.c:4396
#12 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3013
#13 0x000055bf7177559d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=1, 
    pp_stack=0x7fff484ab438, func=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4461
#14 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fff484ab438) at ../Python/ceval.c:4396
#15 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3013
#16 0x000055bf7177559d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=1, 
    pp_stack=0x7fff484ab548, func=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4461
#17 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fff484ab548) at ../Python/ceval.c:4396
#18 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3013
#19 0x000055bf7177559d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=1, 
    pp_stack=0x7fff484ab658, func=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4461
#20 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fff484ab658) at ../Python/ceval.c:4396
#21 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3013
#22 0x000055bf7176d84c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7fd59c240430, globals=<optimized out>, 
    locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, 
    kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=<optimized out>, defs=<optimized out>, 
    defcount=<optimized out>, closure=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3608
#23 0x000055bf7176d34a in PyEval_EvalCode (co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, 
    locals=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:669
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: No, it can only be reproduced on the specific PC and run my program.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more asking related details. Create a minimum piece of code that reproduces the problem, and share it with us.